# Does "Improve Post" on audits make you fail?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

On audits, does hitting *Improve Post* (which tells you you were supposed to reject/accept) count as a failure?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223581/dont-fail-audit-right-away-when-improving-a-suggested-edit)

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic; this Meta split is throwing me off :)

Comment: don't feel bad...it took me a minute to figure out why I didn't have any questions on here :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  In the suggested edit queue, if you try to improve an audit, you will fail the audit.

This is because "improving" an edit is considered to be similar to an approval in the sense that if you decide to improve the post, you are essentially saying that the edit is correct and valid, but it just didn't go far enough.

Howver, in the real world, with actual suggested edits, this isn't always the case since it is easy to back out some poor suggested edits and replace it with a valid one, but 99.999999999% of the time, suggested edit **audits** are so bad that there is no value in salvaging the edit by trying to improve it.  And even if you don't agree, you can just accept the fact that this is how the audits are designed, so when you see one that you think it is an audit, you can reject it, then go back and fix the post in a manner that you see fit.

Comment: I figured. I had one audit where the top half was decently edited (removed a bunch of broken english that was too wordy) and the bottom half had a few bits of random gibberish. It also missed a few things that I wanted to fix, thus I decided to improve and put in the changes necessary and remove the bad parts of the edit.

Comment: And failed the whole damn thing.

Comment: That's the problem with markov-chains. Every once-in-a-while they are correct.